# Type-safe way to remove nulls from Array in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

Is there a preferred and type-safe way without forced typecast to remove nils from Array?

```
[1, nil].select{|x| !!x}
// => Array(Int32 | Nil)
```

Something like special `select`?

P.S.

The use case when I hit this issue - I want to calculate `median` and the `sort` won't work:

```
[1, nil].select{|x| !!x}.sort
```

Map with zeros `[1, nil].map{|x| x || 0}` won't work as unlike let's say `sum` for some operations the length does matter (`median` for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array#compact` will remove nils from the Array:

```
[1, nil].compact # => [1] (Array(Int32))
```